# Dynamically Add forms to table rows Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I'd like to know a good way to add form to a dynamically created tables with jquery. I've added a form in the following way, but when I press the button the function is not called!

I'm new to jquery so I think that there should be a better way to create the tables.

```
$("#aggiornaButton").click(function () {
    //alert('button clicked');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Servizi/selectAllCoseDaFare.php',
        data: "",

        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#coseDaFareBody").empty();

            var formElimina = "<form action='' method='post' name ='eliminaForm' id='eliminaElementoSingolo' class='eliminaForm'>"
                    + "<fieldset>"
                    + "<input type='hidden' name='codID' id='codID'  value='166'/>"
                    + "<button id='eliminaButtonSingolo' class='eliminaButtonSingolo'>elimina</button>"
                    + "</fieldset>"
                    + "</form>";

            $.each(data.risultati, function (idx, obj) {
                if (idx % 2 === 0) {
                    var classe = "<tr><td>"
                } else {
                    var classe = "<tr class='miostile-odd'><td>"
                }
                $("#coseDaFareBody").append(
                        classe + obj.id +
                        "</td><td>" + (obj.dataInserimento || "") +
                        "</td><td>" + (obj.descrizione || "") +
                        "</td><td>" + (obj.dataScadenza || "") +
                        "</td><td>" + (obj.isUrgente || "") +
                        "</td><td>" + (obj.inseritoDa || "") +
                        "</td><td>" + (obj.assegnatoA || "") +
                        "</td><td>" + (obj.fattoDa || "") +
                        "</td><td>" + (obj.isCompletato || "") +
                        "</td><td>" + (obj.dataEsecuzione || "") +
                        "</td><td>" + formElimina +
                        "</td></tr>"
                );
            });
```

The function is:

```
$('.eliminaForm').submit(function (event) {
    var $form = $(this);
    var id = $('#codID', $form).val();
    alert("prova prova prova.");
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: can't repeat ID's in a page, use classes instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **event delegation** for newly created dom elements

```
$(document).on("submit" , '.eliminaForm' , function(event) {
 var $form = $(this);
 var id = $('#codID', $form).val();  
 alert("prova prova prova.");
});
```